# Bootstrap tooltip styling not applying after adding <base href="~/" /> tag

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an existing and quite big `ASP.NET MVC (.NET 6)` project. The project also has included jQuery 3.6.4 and Boostrap 4.4.1.

Recently, I started implementing Blazor server side components in this project and for them to work I needed to add `<base href="~/" />`  tag in the `<head>` (on first line) of the `_Layout.cshtml` file.

And before implementing the Blazor, I had tooltips which would pop up on hover, using the styling from Boostrap (animations, font size etc.).
But after I added the new tag that I mentioned, this specific styling stopped working. I also want to point that I edited all scripts which previously had "~/", because of the new tag.

I checked in the browser Network tab, whether all scripts are executed correctly and they are - for jQuery, and Bootstrap. Check the screenshot (status code 200) from the browser:
[image]

These are my scripts in _Layout:

```
<script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" defer></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            if (typeof ($.fn.popover) == 'function') {
                console.log('Bootstrap is working');
            }
            if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
                console.log('jQuery not working');
            }
            console.log('Script executed.');
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        })
    </script>
```

I've added 2 if validations that I've found on the web, how to check if the scripts are loaded properly. First one logs the message. The second one does not. So it seems that they are loaded.
And the tooltips are enabled using the last line from the script:
`$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()`

Still, I cannot understand why the tooltip styling is not working, after adding this `<base>` tag. Maybe, as plan B, I will style it myself.

Can you help me?

Comment: could you pls provide a minimal-reproduciable sample for us?

Comment: In what format would you like it? And you mean showing you the code in the _Layout?

Comment: I mean, for example, if we don't have similar experience as yours, we may need to create a Net 6 MVC example, then we need to write a tooltip which maybe not the same as yours, then we need to add `<base href="~/" />` in layout page, then should we need to add  some other else code? that's it... if we create such a sample then we can't reproduce the issue...